# Декомпрессор gzip на C++, библиотека zlib.h

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!

Не так давно начал осваивать С++ и столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо разархивировать довольно большое число файлов *.GZ. В связи с этим облазил интернет, нашел библиотеку zlib.h, установил её через configure. И после компиляции, а именно g++ file.cpp -o file -lz получил первые результаты. На самом деле на это у меня ушёл чуть ли не весь день и сейчас задача разархивировать хотя бы 1 файл совсем поставила меня в тупик.

Дело в том, что большинство примеров, которые приводятся на просторах интернета не работали, а один из них выдавал ошибку, мол формат не верный. Это странно, в конце концов эти файлы были получены непосредственно с noaa, поэтому в правильности формата я уверен на все 100%. Например в баше через gunzip они распаковываются на ура.

Собственно нашёл небольшой, в сравнении с остальными, кусочек кода, но он работал. Вот только не так, как мне хотелось бы. Файл действительно стал заполняться информацией, но вместо ожидаемых 2.2 мб, я получал на выходе 14,2 Кб. Так как в языке я совсем не силен, то прошу указать мне, в чем же моя ошибка и как мне получить желаемый результат? Внутри архива находится бинарный файл.

```
#include "zlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const static int KILOB = 16384;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 char cb[KILOB];

 string arch = "/home/cat/Projects/selection_l1b_format_noaa/TEMP/NSS.AMAX.NK.D11172.S2050.E2244.B6813941.GC.gz";
 FILE *outfile = fopen("/home/cat/Projects/selection_l1b_format_noaa/TEMP/AMAX.GC", "wb");

 gzFile gfile = gzopen(arch.c_str(), "rb");

 int len = 0;
 int count = 0;

 do
 {
    len = gzread(gfile, cb, KILOB);
    if (len < KILOB)
        cb[len] = 0;
    count++;
    cout<<"len="<<len<< "   # "<<count <<endl;
    fprintf(outfile, "%s", cb);
 } while (len == KILOB);

fclose(outfile);
gzclose(gfile);
}
```

Если это имеет значение,то моя система Linux Mint 19.1 Код пишу в VSCode, компилятор gcc. И судя по всему я не пользуюсь Qt.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на ваш условный оператор. Вы ничего там не забыли? Фигурных скобок, например?

Comment: На что именно стоит обратить внимание? Логика такова: считываем некоторые количество байт и записываем длину размера буфера в переменную len. Если размер буфера станет меньше макс размера буфера, значит мы приблизились к концу файла и нам стоит изменить его размер на 0, чтобы выйти из цикла. Запись из буфера в исходящий файл будет продолжена в любом случае до тех пор пока цикл окончен не будет.

Comment: Тут проблема еще в том, что вы пытаетесь писать бинарые данные в выходной файл как будто они текстовые. `fprintf(outfile, "%s", cb);` будет печатать строку до первого `'\0'` а не `len` байт, используйте `fwrite`

Comment: @VTT Ваш совет сильно мне помог! Заменил fprintf на fwrite(cb, KILOB, 1, outfile) Также поставил размер буфера 4 байта, получаю абсолютно идентичные файлы, проверил в HEX-редакторе. Так как в конце любой из подобных файлов содержит 4 пустых байта в конце, которые не несут смысловой нагрузки, то, полагаю установить размер буфера на 4 будет оптимальным решением. Я бы хотел ответить Ваш ответ, как верный, но не вижу такой возможности у комментария. Было бы отлично, если бы Вы вынесли этот вариант решения отдельным ответом.